# All Fargate tasks die every 25 minutes

Tags: aws-fargate

Using AWS Fargate to run my REST API. My service is scaled to two tasks. Approximately every ~25 minutes, both tasks get de-registered from the target group and fail health checks at the exact same time.

I am new to Fargate and have no idea what could be causing this. I've looked around and can't find similar problems. I'm not using Fargate Spot as my capacity provider.

Comment: Does logs indicates any error? Also, in terminated tasks you can check the error code

Comment: Only error is the termination message `Handling signal: term`

Comment: The "Stopped Reason" is `Task failed container health checks`

Comment: I've added a third task and now it also fails every ~25 minutes, but with a time-offset from the other two tasks

Comment: It could be caused by high memory consumption. Check the memory used metric for the service and set the statistic as Maximum

Comment: The maximum memory consumption for the past few days is 8%

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. My REST API had a super low throttling limit and was actually throttling my health check after 25 minutes. This caused my tasks to die.